# Looking for ODE integrator/solver with a relaxed attitude to derivative precision

Tags: matlab, math, mathematical-optimization, numerical, scientific-computing

I have a system of (first order) ODEs with fairly expensive to compute derivatives.

However, the derivatives can be computed considerably cheaper to within given error bounds, either because the derivatives are computed from a convergent series and bounds can be placed on the maximum contribution from dropped terms, or through use of precomputed range information stored in kd-tree/octree lookup tables.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any general ODE solvers which can benefit from this; they all seem to just give you coordinates and want an exact result back.  (Mind you, I'm no expert on ODEs; I'm familiar with Runge-Kutta, the material in the Numerical Recipies book, LSODE and the Gnu Scientific Library's solver).

ie for all the solvers I've seen, you provide a `derivs` callback function accepting a `t` and an array of `x`, and returning an array of `dx/dt` back; but ideally I'm looking for one which gives the callback `t`, `x`s, *and an array of acceptable errors*, and receives `dx/dt_min` and `dx/dt_max` arrays back, with the derivative range guaranteed to be within the required precision.  (There are probably numerous equally useful variations possible).

Any pointers to solvers which are designed with this sort of thing in mind, or alternative approaches to the problem (I can't believe I'm the first person wanting something like this) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem as asked here is too dependant on the equations being solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having thought about this some more, it occurred to me that interval arithmetic is probably key.  My `derivs` function basically returns intervals.  An integrator using interval arithmetic would maintain x's as intervals.  All I'm interested in is obtaining a sufficiently small error bound on the `x`s at a final `t`.  An obvious approach would be to iteratively re-integrate, improving the quality of the sample introducing the most error each iteration until we finally get a result with acceptable bounds (although that sounds like it could be a "cure worse than the disease" with regards to overall efficiency).  I suspect adaptive step size control could fit in nicely in such a scheme, with step size chosen to keep the "implicit" discretization error comparable with the "explicit error" ie the interval range).

Anyway, googling "ode solver interval arithmetic" or just "interval ode" turns up a load of interesting new and relevant stuff ([VNODE](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/%7Enedialk/Software/VNODE/VNODE.shtml) and its references in particular).

Comment: You may be interested in Gronwall lemma for computing error bounds.

Comment: Thanks; I didn't know about that; certainly looks relevant!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, if you know f' up to absolute error eps, and integrate from x0 to x1, the error of the integral coming from the error in the derivative is going to be <= eps*(x1 - x0). There is also discretization error, coming from your ODE solver. Consider how big eps*(x1 - x0) can be for you and feed the ODE solver with f' values computed with error <= eps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is a well-posed question.

In many algorithms, *e.g,* nonlinear equation solving, f(x) = 0, an estimate of a derivative f'(x) is all that's required for use in something like Newton's method since you only need to go in the "general direction" of the answer.

However, in this case, the derivative is a primary part of the (ODE) equation you're solving - get the derivative wrong, and you'll just get the wrong answer;  it's like trying to solve f(x) = 0 with only an approximation for f(x).

As another answer has suggested, if you set up your ODE as applied f(x) + g(x) where g(x) is an error term, you should be able to relate errors in your derivatives to errors in your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a stiff system, you will be using some form of implicit method in which case the derivatives are only used within the Newton iteration.  Using an approximate Jacobian will cost you strict quadratic convergence on the Newton iterations, but that is often acceptable.  Alternatively (mostly if the system is large) you can use a Jacobian-free Newton-Krylov method to solve the stages, in which case your approximate Jacobian becomes merely a preconditioner and you retain quadratic convergence in the Newton iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using [odeset](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/odeset.html)? It allows you to set options for an ODE solver, then you pass the options structure as the fourth argument to whichever solver you call. The error control properties (RelTol, AbsTol, NormControl) may be of most interest to you. Not sure if this is exactly the sort of help you need, but it's the best suggestion I could come up with, having last used the MATLAB ODE functions years ago.

In addition: For the user-defined derivative function, could you just hard-code tolerances into the computation of the derivatives, or do you really need error limits to be passed from the solver?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm contributing much, but in the pharma modeling world, we use LSODE, DVERK, and DGPADM. DVERK is a nice fast simple order 5/6 Runge-Kutta solver. DGPADM is a good matrix-exponent solver. If your ODEs are linear, matrix exponent is best by far. But your problem is a little different.

BTW, the T argument is only in there for generality. I've never seen an actual system that depended on T.

You may be breaking into new theoretical territory. Good luck!

Added: If you're doing orbital simulations, seems to me I heard of special methods used for that, based on conic-section curves.

Answer (score 0):

Check into a finite element method with linear basis functions and midpoint quadrature. Solving the following ODE requires only one evaluation each of f(x), k(x), and b(x) per element:

-k(x)u''(x) + b(x)u'(x) = f(x)

The answer will have pointwise error proportional to the error in your evaluations.

If you need smoother results, you can use quadratic basis functions with 2 evaluation of each of the above functions per element.